# are there any way to aggregate multiple API result into single API in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have following URL set which returns JSON API. Now I wonder is there any way to create another API which aggregates all of these API results and return to one ajax call from client side lets say,`url(r'^api/allData/(?P<pk>\d+)$',allData.as_view())`
Does anyone know how to prepare class in views.py to achieve this?

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/envelope/(?P<pk>\d+)$',envelopeData.as_view(),name='api-envelope'),
    url(r'^api/glass/(?P<pk>\d+)$',glassData.as_view(),name='api-glass'),
    url(r'^api/opaque/(?P<pk>\d+)$',opaqueData.as_view(),name='api-opaque'),
    url(r'^api/plant/(?P<pk>\d+)$',plantData.as_view(),name='api-plant'),
    url(r'^api/fan/(?P<pk>\d+)$',fanData.as_view(),name='api-fan'),
    url(r'^api/pump/(?P<pk>\d+)$',pumpData.as_view(),name='api-pump'),
    url(r'^api/people/(?P<pk>\d+)$',peopleData.as_view(),name='api-people'),
    url(r'^api/light/(?P<pk>\d+)$',lightData.as_view(),name='api-light'),
    url(r'^api/smallpower/(?P<pk>\d+)$',spData.as_view(),name='api-sp'),
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you are using **`APIView`**. So, You could call the get() post() methods of the view by using their class object.
 **Here is one Example**

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response


class MyView_One(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(data={"message": self.__class__.__name__})


class MyView_Two(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(data={"message": self.__class__.__name__})


class MyView_Three(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(data={"message": self.__class__.__name__})


class My_All_View(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        return_data = {}
        one = MyView_One()
        return_data.update({"one": one.get(request, pk).data})
        two = MyView_Two()
        return_data.update({"two": two.get(request, pk).data})
        three = MyView_Three()
        return_data.update({"three": three.get(request, pk).data}
        return Response(data=return_data)
```

Use this **`My_All_View`** in your `urls.py` as any other views

**Screenshot**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested serializer, for example:

```
class Serializer1(Serializer):
    ...

class Serializer2(Serializer):
    ....

class Serializer3(Serializer):
    serializer1 = Serializer1()
    serializer2 = Serializer2()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('serializer1', 'serializer2')
```

But about merging views, I do not think.